# How do I speed up inloading of local 'Activity' file in Java?

Tags: java, android-intent, buttonclick

I have a series of XML and Java files - all co-named appropriately (main2.xml, main2activity.java, main3, main4, etc). I'm calling the next named activity (main3) from a Bash command, within each page (main2, in this example).

Everything works, but there's notable delay in execution - is there a more efficient way to load this in, than this?

`am start com.evo.os/.Main3Activity`

They all work, every page does a demo load in, with a 3" delay, as such:

`su -c sleep 3 ; am start com.evo.os/.Main3Activity`

The delay is not in the 3", that's intentional. Trying to direct fire the `am start` bit pauses. Even my regular call via button delays - all of them:

`onEnterButtonClick`fires Main2Activity, and the `onExitButtonClick` fires `finish();` but both with a shocking delay.

Any help?